# Typecasting in java: Integer and Double

Tags: java, casting

Can someone explain how typecasting works in the line int y = (int) x;
Thank You

```
public class typecast
{
 public static void main(String [] args)
 {
  double x=10.5;
  int y=(int) x;
  System.out.println("x="+x);
  System.out.println("y="+y);
 } 
}
```

Comment: Did you try printing the value of `y`. What did you get?? And what didn't you understand?

Comment: can you explain what is it that you find it mysterious in these two lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type cast performs a narrowing type conversion.  The exact conversion depends on the double value, as follows:

- If it is within the range of `int` values, it is rounded towards zero.
- If it outside of the range or is an "Inf" value, then the conversion gives `Integer.MIN_VALUE` or `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, depending on the sign.
- If it is a "NaN" value, the conversion gives zero.

Reference: [JLS 5.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)

Note: "round towards zero" is defined as follows:

> *"The Java programming language uses round toward zero when converting a floating value to an integer (§5.1.3), which acts, in this case, as though the number were truncated, discarding the mantissa bits. Rounding toward zero chooses at its result the format's value closest to and no greater in magnitude than the infinitely precise result.*"

Comment: Much better detailed description for you. Thanks Stephen, I was just too lazy to go look up the specs and put it into something more technical and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, the code won't compile if you try and take a double (variable x) and assign it's value to an int (variable y). So you have to explicitly tell the compiler to cast (convert) the type from a double to an int. When it does that, in this particular case, I believe it drops the fractional part instead of rounding up/down. I could be wrong about that last point.